# Disabling selectize dropdown when a checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectize.js

I have implemented [Selectize](http://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/) on my HTML form. However a dropdown only becomes active when the "enable" *checkbox* is clicked. I know there is a `disable` property on the Selectize object but I dont know how to use it when the *checkbox* is clicked.

I have tried adding the `disabled` class to the Selectize `div` element but that does not work either.
Any help will be well appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 51):

I wanted to add an additional answer here because although @tclark333's answer is correct, it's a bit misleading since the first line is the actual initialization of the selectize object, and not actually what's needed for the answer.

The selectize API is exposed when you access the selectize property on the underlying element from a jQuery object and not as an extension to jQuery itself.

Assuming the element that has been selectized's ID is "myDropDown":

```
//disable
$('#myDropDown')[0].selectize.disable();
//re-enable
$('#myDropDown')[0].selectize.enable();
```

Answer (score 31):

It's a little weird how you have to set it up. Here's what works for me.

```
var select = $("#YourDropDownId").selectize();
var selectize = select[0].selectize;
selectize.disable();
```

Answer (score 2):

This method put automatic locked class to each selectize if parent is readonly (use your own logic to put readonly on select)

```
$('.custom-select-2').each(function(){
    $(this).selectize({
         create: true,
         sortField: {
             field: 'text',
             direction: 'desc'
         }
    });
    if ($(this).is('[readonly]')) {
        $(this)[0].selectize.lock();
    }
})
```

after you can customize the select with this css

```css
select[readonly]{
    pointer-events: none;
    background-color: #e9ecef;
}
.selectize-input.items.full.has-options.has-items.locked {
    background-color: #e9ecef;
}
```

Result:

[example with bootstrap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8b60s.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
function generateCircle(id , jPath){
        var formId =$("#"+id).closest(".data_details_accord").find("form");
        var select = formId.find("select");
        /*disable select initially*/ 
        select.each(function(){
            var thisSelect = $(this).selectize();
            thisSelectDisable = thisSelect[0].selectize;
            thisSelectDisable.disable();
        });

        /***********/ 

        $.ajax({
            url: jPath,
            data:formVlaz,
            success: function(result){

            },error: function (xhr , status, eror) {
            },complete: function (xhr) {

                /*enable select when ajax complete*/ 
                    select.each(function(){
                        var thisSelect = $(this).selectize();
                        thisSelectDisable = thisSelect[0].selectize;
                        thisSelectDisable.enable();
                    });

                /********/ 
            }
        });
    };
```